# I have got an error from page speed insight

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, pagespeed-insights

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ja&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wisebk.com%2F
Our web site got an error
Sometimes it is ERROR TIMEOUT , sometimes ACCESS DENIED error.
Does anybody know why this website got an error on page speed insight?

https://www.wisebk.com/
This is wordpress website.

Answer (score 0):

Because your site doesn't respond fast enough, it took nearly 30 seconds to send the first byte (for your server to respond).

This could be a regional thing as Page Speed Insights servers are in the US (and I am in UK) so [perhaps read this answer on how to run Lighthouse locally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64511869/2702894) (the engine behind Page Speed Insights) and see if that works (or initially just run Lighthouse in Google Chrome Developer Tools).

Other than that it is a symptom of an overloaded server or something that is wrong with your theme (perhaps trying to dynamically build the page from the database and there is a very long running database query), could be hundreds of things but that is the reason Page Speed Insights isn't working for you.

[image: 30 seconds to first byte]