# Google Lighthouse how to explicitly mark my site as NOT being a PWA

Tags: google-chrome, lighthouse

Im regularly running the Lighthouse tool and getting a result for PWA.

I know I can untick the check on the chrome interface but wondering is there a way I can set my configuration to say "Not a PWA" so this check stops running?

This site is not designed to be a PWA and I'd like to just mark it as so and be done with it.

Comment: are you running the CLI or just running Lighthouse in the browser?

Comment: Currently just in the browser but Im interested in answers for either approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the browser it should remember your settings, so if you turn PWA test off it should be off for each run. Unfortunately if your browser keeps resetting this there isn't much you can do in the developer tools version of Lighthouse.

However if you are willing to install the [Google Lighthouse Command Line Interface (CLI)](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) then you have full control and can automate the process.

I wrote about [the benefits of using the Lighthouse CLI here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64511869/2702894)

To run Lighthouse without the PWA check you would run something similar to the following:

`lighthouse https://yoursite.com --only-categories=performance,accessibility,best-practices,performance,seo --output html --output-path ./reports/not-a-pwa-report.html`

The key part being `--only-categories=` and then the tests you want to run.

The above example would output the HTML report to the specified path. All the [options are listed on the linked Lighthouse page under CLI options](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse#cli-options).