# How to detect browser support for @font-face descriptors using CSS.supports()

Tags: css, font-face

You can detect if a browser supports a specific or multiple CSS features using the `CSS.supports` function. It can receive two parameters, the first one is the name of the feature and the second one is the value. For example, if you run `CSS.supports("gap", "1rem")`, it'll return a `boolean` indicating if the browser supports the feature or not.

But if you run `CSS.supports("font-display", "swap")` or try to check if the browser supports any other *@font-face descriptors*, the function will always return `false`.

So, what is the correct syntax or way to detect support for @font-face descriptors using the `CSS.supports()` function? Or, is it even possible? If not then is there any alternative way?

Comment: I found many ways to detect but not sure are these work for you. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339268/is-there-a-way-to-detect-whether-a-users-browser-is-supporting-font-face), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/check), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845/how-to-detect-which-one-of-the-defined-font-was-used-in-a-web-page). Some of them are not supported cross browsers, please check that again.

Comment: "CSS font-display is a `@font-face` descriptor and not a property, so its support in the browser cannot be tested with feature queries (CSS `@supports` rule and CSS.supports API).": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66117975/how-to-test-font-display-swap-on-your-local-machine

Comment: @Terry Yeah, you are definitely right.

Comment: Thank you @vee. The links you mentioned don't have a direct solution to the problem but all of them have some related information. This one is good https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/check. I didn't know about this API.